# Cant figure out login with facebook using Oauth2.0

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth, facebook-authentication

I'm new to the whole system about logging in with facebook. I just read about the OAuth2.0 system by facebook and i did understand how it works but i'm unable to understand how to make it work with my app and get the access token and then getting info from the graph api.

```
    <a href="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=241467205957761&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/optionsminer&client_secret=17b3847f0d32667eb75ac3270fcbdbe7">asdasda</a>
```

For example if i have this, it doesnt seem to work and its giving me json of error

```
        {
        "error": {
       "message": "Error validating client secret.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 1
        }
```

I'm not sure what to do with this further. If anyone of you guys could guide me through a bit it'd be great! 
Thanks!
}

Comment: Are you making a mobile or web app? and did you authenticate?

Comment: Just trying to make a sign in with facebook feature.

Comment: I noticed you removed your app secret from the code through an edit, please not though that this is still saved, so as @CBroe suggested, make sure you go the app settings and reset it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [working examples from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/).

If you are building an app purely in javascript, you will be using only your `client_id`. The `client_secret` is for requesting token from server-side code (e.g. a Rails or PHP application).

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Client-side OAuth Example</title> 
  </head> 
<body> 
<script> 
  function displayUser(user) {
    var userName = document.getElementById('userName');
    var greetingText = document.createTextNode('Greetings, ' + user.name + '.');
    userName.appendChild(greetingText);
  }

  var appID = YOUR_APP_ID;
  if (window.location.hash.length == 0) {
    var path = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?';
    var queryParams = ['client_id=' + appID,
                       'redirect_uri=' + window.location,
                       'response_type=token'];
    var query = queryParams.join('&');
    var url = path + query;
    window.open(url);
  } else {
    var accessToken = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    var path = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?";
    var queryParams = [accessToken, 'callback=displayUser'];
    var query = queryParams.join('&');
    var url = path + query;

    // use jsonp to call the graph
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);        
 }
</script> 
<p id="userName"></p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don’t put your app secret in client-side code – it’s called a *secret* for a reason!**

(If that’s your *real* app id and secret in the code you posted, you should get a new secret immediately!)

Are you using any of the SDKs? Look into the JavaScript SDK for client-side login, or the PHP SDK if you’re working with PHP and want to do server-side login. These SDKs help you with things like OAuth login and keep the very basic stuff out of your hands, so you can concentrate on app functionality …